# Reverse engineer c# into a format that can be imported to LucidCharts

Tags: c#, .net, uml, visio, lucidchart

I am trying to come up with a way to import our current large application into a UML diagram for LucidCharts. LucidCharts supports a vdx XML format from visio. I'm just mainly trying to find a way to do this easily instead of typing each class name and method into LucidCharts. Linking and call chain linking I don't care about as much as I can do that myself.

Are there any easy solutions, or something I can do to read the meta data and make a vdx complaint file?

Comment: If this wasn't a real question, why was ElYusubov able to get close to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are several open source & commercial tools that will create UML diagram from the C# project and visa-verse. As example, i will try to list three of them:

**Option #1:** Try to use the [Modelmaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/modelmaker/index.html). It can work with both Delphi and C#. 
I should add that it does more than just diagrams, it can be used for reverse engineering, refactoring and the like. It's been going for a while now and has many great features.

**Option #2:** You may also try NDepend tool for .NET developers. It comes with both a dependency graph and a dependency matrix and integrates in VS. The graph and matrix can be generated from .NET assemblies and they are interactive. You can [download and use the free trial edition](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) for a while and make your own opinion.

**Option #3:** The Guys at Tigris.org have also done some work on this.
Here is the [Open Source Link](http://argouml-csharp.tigris.org/) to the project. It is also very impressive.